# How to get Param value from XGBoost4J?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, xgboost

I'm using Spark XGBoost4j with the Pyspark wrapper (https://github.com/sllynn/spark-xgboost), and I would like to know the name of the contributions column of a model.
When I do:

```py
xgboost = XGBoostClassifier(
    featuresCol="features",
    labelCol="labelCol",
    predictionCol="prediction",
    contribPredictionCol="contribs",
    seed=42,
)
xgboost.getParam("contribPredictionCol")
```

it outputs:

```
Param(parent='XGBoostClassifier_998c81888fa3', name='contribPredictionCol', doc='name of the predictContrib results')
```

However, I would like it to output: "contribs". How can I achieve this? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so I have found a way:

```py
original_name = None
for k, v in xgboost.extractParamMap().items():
    if "contribPredictionCol" in k.name:
        original_name = v
```